# jQuery selector with string object not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

```
var theHTML = '<html><head><title>Hi</title><link rel="apple-icon-touch-precomposed" href="icon.jpg" /></head><body></body></html>';
alert($(theHTML).find('link[rel="apple-icon-touch-precomposed"]').attr('href'));
```

It alerts "undefined." I want it to return "icon.jpg". What is wrong?

Comment: Browsers are going to treat this differently. Some will strip away some of the outer elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
alert($(theHTML).filter('link[rel="apple-icon-touch-precomposed"]').attr('href'));
```

That is, use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WmwRU/

If you do a `console.log($(theHTML))` you'll see why.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) not [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) when selecting on HTML like that.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3V9K/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want that for, but if you use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** instead of `find()` it'll work as you want:

```
var theHTML = '<html><head><title>Hi</title><link rel="apple-icon-touch-precomposed" href="icon.jpg" /></head><body></body></html>';
alert($(theHTML).filter('link[rel="apple-icon-touch-precomposed"]').attr('href'));
```

[**<kbd>JSFiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/aRgzD/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use `.find` that way, I'd have to read the API about it. But, you can try `.prop('href')` instead of `.attr('href')`. If that doesn't work, I'd also suggest using an `*` after the `=` like `link[rel=*"apple-icon-touch-precomposed"]`